# RDP sessions logs out VNC session?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vnc

I have situation on my Windows 7 machine, where is active RDP service and running VNC (TightVNC) server. Let's say, that I'm logged in via VNC (VNC viewer). Then I want to connect via RDP. At this moment my VNC session is blocked (I mean in VNC viewer Windows login screen shows up, example from web: https://static.squarespace.com/static/514e2905e4b023ca28fd2047/514e2ad8e4b0d528d07c0c96/514e2ae0e4b0d528d07c1450/1323212468000/login11.png). And this login screen interrupts my scripts running in background. How can I switch it off, that new RDP connection will not lock my logged user?

Comment: That's how RDP behaves, it drops the current user back to the login screen, therefore cannot be used for screensharing etc. I'd use TeamViewer if you want uninterrupted viewing/sharing.

Answer (score 2):

> Unlike server editions of Windows, Microsoft limits the client
>   editions of Windows to one concurrent user, whether remote or local.
>   So if a remote desktop connection is made, no one physically at the PC
>   can use it or even see the desktop without first kicking off the
>   remote user.

https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/how-to-enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows.html

Therefore,
you need to enable concurrent remote desktop connections, which means multiple logons. Unlike other tools, this tool (RDP Wrapper) does not alter termsrv.dll.

https://github.com/binarymaster/rdpwrap/releases

Answer (score 0):

I know two alternatives, but each has limitations:

- You have to launch VNC Server on the remote session as "application" instead of "service". In this way, you can see the RDP session but you can't interact with its UAC.
- TightVNC Server from the version 2.8.53 support connection to an active RDP Session but you have to disable query to "accept/reject").